# .NET merge object into other object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a huge class with a lot of information. Some information of that I want to print to JSON, but not all information. When I serialize the Object to JSON it off course prints all information.

So I thought I made a template Class for the data I do want to print in JSON. And then I want to copy all values that do exist in the template from the original class and skip the rest. Then I can serialize that template Class.

For example:
[image]

Now what I try to accomplish is to copy the data from `place` to `placeJSON`.

[image]

So the result  will be something like this:[image]

I thought I should loop over all properties in `placeJSON` and if the same property name exist in `place` then I should copy that value. But it also needs to be done for nested classes like `Country`.

How is this possible to do?

Comment: Many JSON libraries support attributes for marking certain properties that shouldn't be serialized. Check the documentation for the serializer you're using.

Comment: @mason Serious... So I am on the wrong path all along? I use Newtonsoft JSON. I'll check that documentation

Comment: `JsonIgnoreAttribute`

Comment: As @mason said, if you are using Newtonsoft.JSON, there is an attribute named `JsonIgnore` (at least in C#) where you specify which property you want the serializer to ignore.

Comment: @all this is not quite what I need. See `JsonIgnore` is placed inside the class and those properties will be ignored, always. But sometimes I need some other data in JSON then another time. `JsonIgnore` isn't very flexible as it ignores it always.

Comment: The two 'R's, Reflection and Recursion.

Comment: @NLAnaconda - Please don't post code as images without also posting the code as text. When it is as text then we can copy, paste, and write an answer using your code. As images you end up with less answers.

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a solution and share it here. It is probably not flawless yet but it is a start.

```
Public Shared Function mergeObjectInTemplatedata(template As Object, 
                                                 source As Object, 
                                                 Optional parents As List(Of String) = Nothing) As Object

    If parents Is Nothing Then
        parents = New List(Of String)
    End If

    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In template.GetType().GetProperties()

        Dim value As Type = prop.GetValue(template).GetType()
        If value = GetType(String) Or value = GetType(Integer) Then

            prop.SetValue(template, getFromSource(source, parents, prop.Name))

        Else
            parents.Add(prop.Name)
            mergeObjectInTemplatedata(prop.GetValue(template), source, parents)
        End If

    Next

    Return template
End Function

Private Shared Function getFromSource(source As Object, 
                                      location As List(Of String), 
                                      propertyName As String) As Object

    Dim obj As Object = source
    For Each item As String In location
        obj = CallByName(obj, item, CallType.Get)
    Next
    Return CallByName(obj, propertyName, CallType.Get)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't just create a new anonymous type to serialize into JSON?

For example (I only know C#, not VB, and the question is tagged as C#, so I hope this is usable!):

```
class Place {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public CountryItem Country { get; set; }
      //other properties...
      public object ToPlaceJson() {
            return new { name = Name, country = Country };
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I wanted to do it this way is because I have to do this a lot (realy lot) of times. I thought it was easy just to merge the one into another instead of writing `name = Name`,`country=Country`, `latitude=Latitude`, `longitude=Longitude`, ..,...,... [* 100 times]. I thought if the names are the same it should be possible to do it programmaticly.